# CSS styling issue-chrome while using display:inline-block

Tags: css, google-chrome, styling

```
<div class="hi>
    <div class="hello">name</div>
     <div class="world"><img /></div>
</div>
.hi{
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
 }
 .hello{
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      height: 22px;
      margin: 3px 0;
      max-width: 80%;
      overflow: hidden;
 }
 .world{
       background: url("***") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
       display: inline-block;
       height: 13px;
       left: 5px;
       position: relative;
       top: -9px;
       width: 14  
}
```

The issue is when the name is exceeding and max width is applied the background image in world div appears misaligned(appears slightly above), while the name for which max-width is not getting applied displays it correctly.

The idea is name and image should be in the same line.with name center aligned and image next to it. and if name exceeds it should be truncated so that the image doesn't get displayed in the next line. i am giving background image since i have an image inside a image.

the issue happens in chrome alone.

Comment: Can you give us what the generated output is or what your intention is? Somewhat vague right now.

Comment: it appears like this:  kumar<sup>image</sup> when max width is getting applied and kum <image> when max-width is not getting applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-width: 80%` doesn't mask the fact that `<div>` is a block-level element. When a width is not explicitly set, it will always be `width:100%` inherently. If you set the width of `.hello` to `80%`, I think you'll see what you're expecting.

Comment: I tried and it worked. Bu my requirement is the image should be next to the text. So if i set the width as 80% the image would always be distant. if i give max-width, the image would be next to the text whenever the full max -width is not getting occupied.  i changed my div to span and label. the same issue occurs

Comment: If i dont specify a width and display it as inline, the design collapses when the name exceeds the block. and since i want the name to be centered giving <code>float:left</code> was not a viable option.Th idea is name and image should be in the same line.with name center aligned and image next to it. and if name exceeds it should be truncated so that the image doesnt move to the next line.

Comment: The only way you'll be able to successfully truncate is by setting a `height` on both the text element and the image. This doesn't guarantee that clipping will occur. I suggest rethinking the design as that can affect accessibility. I've created an example here with what I believe you're trying to accomplish. Notice the text is clipped http://codepen.io/anon/pen/shmla

Comment: I have already set the height for those elements . in my css , you would find that the height has been set for text and the image.

Comment: inline-block by default will make them align on the bottom. Can't tell you how many times I forget that :)

Comment: well i learnt the lesson today after fiddling with very possible combination.